# When to use alter-var-root with (constantly)?

Tags: clojure

I encountered something like this in a program:

```
(defonce foo nil)
(alter-var-root #'foo (constantly 4))
```

Since the code above uses ***constantly***, is there any reason to prefer it to a simple ***def***, like below?

```
(def foo 4)
```

Is it just to make it more consistent with the ***defonce***, or there are downsides to using def?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(ns banana)
(defonce foo nil)

(ns user)
(use 'banana)

foo ;=> nil

(alter-var-root #'foo (constantly 42))
foo ;=> 42

(def foo 50)
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: foo already refers to: #'banana/foo in namespace: user
```